# admin-ajax.php returning error 400 namespaced callback

Tags: php, ajax

I'm writing a plugin and I'm getting an error `400 Bad Request` from admin-ajax.php. I did some poking around in the Wordpress core about this and it seems where it's getting hung up is around line 85 of admin-ajax.php which checks if the ajax action is registered or not:

```
if ( ! has_action( 'wp_ajax_' . $_REQUEST['action'] ) ) {
    wp_die( '0', 400 );
}
```

Here's my code:

PHP

```
namespace PluginName\options;
add_action('wp_ajax_collection_sync', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\handle_ajax_post_request');
function handle_ajax_post_request(){
    error_log('success');
    echo 'success';
    wp_die();
}
```

JS

```
var data = {
    action : 'collection_sync',
};

$.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response){
    if( response === 'success' ){
        // handle success (update progress bar, output success message w/e)
        console.log('hoo rah');
    }
    else{
        // handle fail (update progress bar, output error message w/e)
        console.log('uh oh');
    }
});
```

The error comes as a surprise to me because when I check the returned value from  `has_action('wp_ajax_collection_sync')` under the line I run 
`add_action('wp_ajax_collection_sync', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\handle_ajax_post_request');` it's return value is true. Also when I run `error_log($_REQUEST['action'])` directly above line 85 in admin-ajax.php it's value is `collection_sync`. I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the fact that I'm using a namespaced callback or not. Anyway I'm stumped and would love some help. Thanks!!

Comment: If this code is not only for wp-admin, add `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_collection_sync', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\handle_ajax_post_request');` https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned but this is code being run on the admin side by a plugin. So itll need to be run from the wp_ajax hook afaik.

Comment: Have you try to dump `$_REQUEST['action']` before the if statement in `admin-ajax.php` ? And what is return ?

Comment: Yes thanks (i mentioned this in my question). It returns `collection_sync`

Comment: Have you tried the same exact code without using the `__NAMESPACE__` constant? If you are using a later version of PHP you can pass the callback directly into the second parameter of `add_action`. Might help you figure out if the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks and yeah I've tried that too. I wound up fixing my plugin by reverting to a much earlier commit when it was working and re-building everything else from there. An unfortunate way to go but I had to keep the project moving. I assume the problem must've been from elsewhere in the plugin because the code in the OP siloed should be sound. Thanks everyone for your help.